# Can we use two summary tags in a single details tag?

Tags: html

I tried to use two summary tags in a single details tag in html. But it is not reflecting any change in the browser page.

So I want to know whether can we use two summary tags in a single details tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `<details>` tag can have only one `<summary>` tag and it should be *first child* only

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary